# Android button style for date picker

Tags: android, button, styles

I was wondering if there is a standard style for buttons (or what is it?) with date-time?
I'm looking for exactly this field style:

[image: Screenshot]

Is it something from standard styles? Or I should use drawable for make this right bottom corner?

Comment: That looks to be a standard Spinner in the Holo Theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard Spinner in the Holo Theme.

If you want to bring Holo to your app, please use: [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere)

Or if you want something new, something difference, try to use other Android Picker widget [android-wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)